# HTML text formatting

Tags: html, css

hopefully this is a really easy question.  I'm trying to achieve the following style of formatting without using tables, as illustrated in the first picture.  Is there a way to style the text content using span and/or div tags to make it look like the example at the bottom?  Your insight is appreciated.

**Using a table**

[image: Table Formatting]

**Desired Look**

[image]

Update:

Thank you all for your suggestions, I wasn't sure if it was standard to use tables in this case or not.

Comment: Have you considered using `<pre>` tags to maintain source formatting?

Comment: Or, perhaps, sharing your current mark-up with us?

Comment: I hate to say it, but you're presenting tabular data....hence TABLES.  Since it's data as opposed to a page layout, you're only going to be creating more work for yourself (and more page overhead to load) doing it without tables.  If it's styling you're worried about, that's simple with CSS...we'll even help you!

Comment: I would also go with a table for displaying tabular data, that is what tables are for. Nothing wrong with using a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind having a fixed-width left column, try this:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/WmkxD/)

**HTML:**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Instructions</dt>
    <dd>ABC, 123<br />ABC, 123<br /></dd>
    <dt>Example</dt>
    <dd>ABC, 123<br />ABC, 123<br /></dd>
</dl>

Floats are cleared.
```

**CSS:**

```
dl {
   overflow: hidden
}
dt, dd {
    float: left;
    width: 100px
}
dt {
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 9px 0 0
}
```

Although it isn't:

> using span and/or div tags

I believe that my choice of tag makes more semantic sense here.

Comment: @Loktar: Thanks for reminding me to use word "semantic" there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mind having a fixed-width left column at all.  Thanks again for yours and everyone else's support.

Comment: It was no problem. If you like, you can remove that half-comment by [clicking the delete button](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_Xb25fTcjIRQ/S9ZXtLipMXI/AAAAAAAAAMQ/DwsOB1IWcAM/SO-comment.PNG).

Comment: Haha, thanks again thirtydot, I always wondered if that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS:

```
table
{
    border; 0;
}
```

If that doesn't work then you probably have a border setting in your HTML:

```
<table border="1">
```

Or something like that, remove the declaration and use CSS as above :)

Comment: Just to clear confusion, I consciously turned on the border in the first picture above just to demonstrate how I have the table structured.

Answer (score 1):

Ready for some Div soup?

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/WSqRR/5/

**Markup**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class='left'>
        Instructions:
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <p>ABC,123</p>
        <p>ABC,123</p>
    </div>
    <br class='clear'/>
    <div class='left'>
        Im so long thats right LONG:
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <p>ABC,123</p>
        <p>ABC,123</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{width:auto;}
.left,.right{float:left;text-align:right; width:50%;}
.right{float: right; text-align:left;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Try changing one of your instances of the word "Instructions" to something longer.

Answer (score 1):

A [definition/description list](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/) might be suitable for your purposes. Here's an [example of how styling it might work](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/DMfD6/2/) accordingly.

HTML:

```
<dl class="in">
    <dt>Instructions</dt>
    <dd>ABC, 123<br>ABC, 123</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="ex">
    <dt>Examples</dt>
    <dd>ABC, 123<br>ABC, 123</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl { clear:both; margin:0 0 1em; }
dl dt { color:#666; width:7em; float:left; margin:0 1em 0 0; text-align:right; }
dl dd { margin:0 0 0 8em; }
```

Comment: 13 mins too late...I don't know why I even make an attempt, lol.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<p class="title">Instructions:</p>
<p>ABC,123</p>
<p>ABC,123</p>
<p class="title">Examples:</p>
<p>ABC,123</p>
<p>ABC,123</p>
```

CSS:

```
p
{
    margin-left: 210px;
}
.title
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
    text-align:right;
    float:left;
}
```

though I have to say, as mentioned in answers above, it does look a bit like tabular data. In which case using tables is okay.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/TZpXd/